Compose basic empty view similar to View in android view system
Is there any basic view widget in Compose, similar to the View class or <View>...</View> tag of android view system, to which we can pass a modifier to place it appropriately in a layout and can pass some background to it?

Yes, you can use Box for that.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .padding(16.dp)
) {
    // your view
}

If you just need a simple visual gap, or an empty space with a configuration by modifier, you can use Spacer
Spacer(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(50.dp)
        .background(Color.Gray)
)


Yes, currently I am using Row {} with single modifier parameter because modifier alone can fulfill my requirement, but that's exactly why I am looking for a more basic composable optimum for my simple requirement like View and unlike layout-based composables e.g. Box, Row, Column etc which have unnecessary tons of features related to laying out their children.

what I understand from your comment, you need to just have a view which will have size and background. then, you can use Spacer. I have updated my post based on that

Great! was looking something exactly like this! It doesn't even have a input Composable parameter. It only has modifier parameter which is sufficient for my need. Can draw most common shapes by combination of clip() and background() of it e.g. [upper/bottom/left/right]+rounded-corner-rectangles, etc without using unnecessary layout widgets.
